# Error getting default calendar, comes only first time but after that works fine

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

I have written a code to create an event. 
Code is pretty straight forward :

```
    let eventStore : EKEventStore = EKEventStore()
    eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: {
            granted, error in
            if (granted) && (error == nil) {
                print("granted \(granted)")
                print("error  \(String(describing: error))")

            let event:EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
            event.title = title
            event.startDate = startDate
            event.endDate = endDate
            event.notes = "Lecture"
            event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
            //                eventStore.saveEvent(event, span: EKSpanThisEvent, error: nil)
            guard ((try? eventStore.save(event, span: EKSpan.thisEvent, commit: true)) != nil)else{
                print("error  saving event")
                completion(false)
                return
            }
            print("Saved Event")
        }}
```

When the code runs first time it gives this error :

> [EventKit] Error getting default calendar for new events: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1019 "(null)"
>   2018-05-18 00:18:16.586150+0500 SevimFahrschuleMobile[11413:3650672] [EventKit] No object ID provided.  Will not find out if the object exists.

But when I run this code again, it works. 
I am not getting.
There is kind of similar question here but the solution there is to get authorization for reminders and then save event, i.e

```
eventStore.requestAccess(to: .reminder) { (<#Bool#>, <#Error?#>) in
        <#code#>
    }
```

which sounds totally illogical to me.

Let me know if you see any reason for first time failure.
Thanks

Comment: Hey, did you find the solution after?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in **Info.plist** :

> NSCalendarsUsageDescription
>   NSRemindersUsageDescription

Comment: If this was the problem then the code wouldn't work the second time.

Comment: I've already added NSCalendarsUsageDescription and since I am not using Reminders, other one is not needed, otherwise xcode will crash